# Exist a universal way to open files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, universal

I'm working in a wordcloud and I was thinking in a way to open whatever file as an input chosen by the user. For example, an docx file like input and exctrat all text on it and do the wordcloud. Or use a csv file or txt file, something like that.

I've tried with some libraries like pandas, but por each type of document I spent some lines of code and 'if loops' to test the type of the file.

Maybe:

But I'm not very sure about that.

Comment: Maybe: open('file', r):

Comment: But word documents are binary...

Comment: You'll really have be more specific, especially about what you've tried. SO is not a free design and coding site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use different libraries for every extension, because you can't simply skip the headers and then read the content.
At least not using just some variant of "with a as open("path")"